# How to pair multiple zone valve relays

Tags: wiring, hvac

I have two R845A zone valve relays for hydronic heating. I want to pair them together so they’re controlled by one stat (both on or off at the same time). How can I wire them up? Do I put a zone panel in front of the relays?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is wire the relays in parallel.